# PHP script to create db and allow remote access is not working

Tags: mysql, database, permissions, pdo, remote-connection

I have 2 servers. `Server A` (10.0.0.1) and `Server B` (10.0.0.2) [not real ips]. `Server A` houses the script to create databases on remote `Server B`. The databases are created on the fly. The script on `Server A` is as follows:

```
$this->dbh->exec("CREATE DATABASE `" . $name . "`;
     CREATE USER '" . $username . "'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '" . $password . "';
     GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `" . $name . "`.* TO '" . $username . "'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '" . $password . "' WITH GRANT OPTION;
     FLUSH PRIVILEGES;")
```

This script connects to `Server B` and uses a mysql admin account.
This creates the user and db on `Server B` just fine. Right after executing,
I close the current admin connection and open a new connection as the newly created user to create a couple tables.
This is when I receive the following error `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user.......`;

Now when I log into my hosting account and choose "Allow remote connections" I can then run the query fine from Server A as the new user. There seems to be something wrong with my grant permission from the get go. As you can see I use the wildcard `%` to allow a connection from any IP so I am not sure where the statement goes wrong. I can supply more information if needed. Any help is greatly, greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure but that `@localhost` looks suspicious to me. why run `CREATE USER`  at all? `GRANT` will already create it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out all I had to do was replace `"'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '"` with

`"'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '"` "PASSWORD" was not needed. After I removed it, I was able to connect remotely.